# содержимое списка есть в unity но нет в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d

Список visibleItems успешно заполняется, но при выполнении TakeItem() содержимого не оказывается на месте. Хотя unity показывает что список полон.

Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?

```
public class Player : Creature
{
    public List<GameObject> visibleItems;
    public List<GameObject> inventory;


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Item")
        {
            log.text = log.text + "\n " + "Ты видишь " + coll.gameObject.name + "!";
            Debug.Log("Ты видишь " + coll.gameObject.name + "!");

            visibleItems.Add(coll.gameObject);//объект исправно попадает в visibleItems
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Item")
        {
            visibleItems.Remove(coll.gameObject);//объект на месте и успешно удаляется
        }
    }


    public void TakeItem()// при вызове метода, список visibleItems отображается в unity заполненным
    {
        Debug.Log("TakeItem");
        foreach (GameObject o in visibleItems) //список оказывается пустым!
        {
            visibleItems.Remove(o);
            o.SetActive(false);
            inventory.Add(o);
            Debug.Log("Ты берешь " + o.gameObject.name);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: По коду вроде бы все у вас правильно. Может в редакторе не обновляется состояние так быстро как вам хочется, я при отладке сталкивался с подобными вещами. Может зальете куда нибудь проект попробую глянуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все еще актуально - код не будет работать, так как вы меняете перебираемую коллекцию в foreach. Накидал на Unity тестовый скрипт - падает в ошибку и ругается как раз на то что коллекция изменяется при переборе, хотя возможно ваша версия Unity ругается как-то по-другому.

Раз в конце перебора visibleItems остается пустым, то можно так:

```
public void TakeItem()
{
    Debug.Log("TakeItem");
    foreach (GameObject o in visibleItems)
    {
        o.SetActive(false);
        inventory.Add(o);
        Debug.Log("Ты берешь " + o.gameObject.name);
    }

    visibleItems.Clear();
}
```

Кроме того, если это не упрощение кода - надо помнить, что в лист inventory попадает отключенный GameObject.